# modal diglog box in mvc

Tags: jquery

how to build/develop a modal diglog box in mvc and how to pop it up on click of a button in jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modal would likely already be in the source of the page already, unless it's something that requires an AJAX call.  This is pretty simple to do, and I'd look into the jQuery UI library for their 'dialog' styles. This does pretty much exactly what you want.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

From there it's as easy as binding it in jQuery and calling it on click:

```
<script>
$(function(){
  $('#click-for-modal').click(function(){
    $('#my-modal-div').dialog();
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank u . Its useful. i have a doubt . When i hav $ div 'my-modal-div'in UI , before the Button click event it wil be displayed na.

Comment: Did you incorporate it the way I did in the example above? The jQuery selector that calls `dialog()` is bound to the `onClick` event for another button. If you do it this way it should work flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [jQuery-UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)